# xslt-processor gives back top-results on one dataset and no results on another

Tags: mysql, xml, parsing, xslt

hello and good day dear xml-friends,

i am new to xml so do not bear with me for the questions... i am currently making some tests with an xslt-processor - 
I ve got an script that   runs nicely on one test-dataset - and gives back good and valid results and contrary to this behaviour
i get back silly and dumb results if i run the same script - note: i get back a csv-formatted file with 2 MB that contains 
only tabstops... funny  but true...

so here my script is:

if i run this xslt-code on the following test-dataset i get only bad bad results - only tabstops... nothing more... what causes this errors. note - i get better results if i run the code againgst the second dataset .- see far below... and see  the results at the end of this inital posting....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="osm">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node[tag[@k='amenity' and @v='restaurant']]">
        <xsl:value-of select="./@id"/>
        <xsl:text>&#x09;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="./@lat"/>
        <xsl:text>&#x09;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="./@lon"/>
        <xsl:text>&#x09;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="./tag[@k = 'cuisine']/@v"/>
        <xsl:text>&#x09;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="./tag[@k = 'name']/@v"/>
        <xsl:text>&#x09;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="./tag[@k = 'wheelchair']/@v"/>
        <xsl:text>&#x09;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="./tag[@k = 'website']/@v"/>
        <xsl:text>&#x09;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="./tag[@k = 'addr:country']/@v"/>
        <xsl:text>&#x09;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="./tag[@k = 'addr:city']/@v"/>
    <xsl:text>&#x09;</xsl:text>        
        <xsl:value-of select="./tag[@k = 'addr:street']/@v"/>
        <xsl:text>&#x09;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="./tag[@k = 'addr:housenumber']/@v"/>
        <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
        <!-- all non-restaurant nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="node[tag[@k='amenity' and @v!='restaurant']]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

if i run this against this test-dataset - then i get only dumb results  a file with only tabstops in. i have no glue what causes the error?

```
<node id="25242198" lat="49.0077605" lon="8.3560676" version="9" changeset="10151199" user="keinname" uid="165061" timestamp="2011-12-18T22:59:43Z">
    <tag k="addr:city" v="Karlsruhe" />
    <tag k="addr:country" v="DE" />
    <tag k="addr:housenumber" v="6" />
    <tag k="addr:postcode" v="76185" />
    <tag k="addr:street" v="Durmersheimer Straße" />
    <tag k="amenity" v="restaurant" />
    <tag k="beer_garden" v="yes" />
    <tag k="cuisine" v="german" />
    <tag k="name" v="Beim Schupi" />
    <tag k="opening_hours" v="Mo-Sa 17:00+; Su 12:00+" />
    <tag k="phone" v="+49 721 551220" />
    <tag k="website" v="http://www.schupi.de" />
</node>
```

[...]...

Note: i get back silly and bad results - only tabstops and nothing more..

but if if i run the above mentioned xslt-processor-code on the following xml-dataset i get back good results... see below - !!!

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="Osmosis SNAPSHOT-r26564">
  <node id="185612117" version="5" timestamp="2011-01-08T19:23:43Z" uid="290680" user="wheelmap_visitor" changeset="6906586" lat="48.8037523" lon="9.5248779">
    <tag k="addr:postcode" v="73614"/>
    <tag k="wheelchair" v="yes"/>
    <tag k="website" v="http://www.courage-restaurant.de/"/>
    <tag k="addr:country" v="DE"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Courage"/>
    <tag k="amenity" v="restaurant"/>
    <tag k="addr:street" v="Künkelinstraße"/>
    <tag k="addr:city" v="Schorndorf"/>
    <tag k="addr:housenumber" v="33"/>
  </node>
  <node id="252619189" version="5" timestamp="2011-01-08T19:21:43Z" uid="290680" user="wheelmap_visitor" changeset="6906586" lat="48.8067032" lon="9.5314986">
    <tag k="addr:postcode" v="73614"/>
    <tag k="wheelchair" v="yes"/>
    <tag k="website" v="www.kesselhaus-schorndorf.de"/>
    <tag k="addr:country" v="DE"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Kesselhaus"/>
    <tag k="amenity" v="restaurant"/>
    <tag k="addr:street" v="Arnoldstraße"/>
    <tag k="addr:city" v="Schorndorf"/>
    <tag k="addr:housenumber" v="3"/>
  </node>
  <node id="319597380" version="1" timestamp="2008-12-17T21:13:15Z" changeset="444629" lat="48.8277913" lon="9.5477029">
    <tag k="name" v="Gasthaus zur Linde"/>
    <tag k="amenity" v="restaurant"/>
  </node>
  <node id="319597382" version="1" timestamp="2008-12-17T21:13:15Z" changeset="444629" lat="48.8282523" lon="9.5503109">
    <tag k="name" v="China-Garden"/>
    <tag k="amenity" v="restaurant"/>
  </node>
  <node id="339591124" version="2" timestamp="2011-09-22T17:33:36Z" uid="290680" user="wheelmap_visitor" changeset="9366746" lat="48.7888015" lon="9.5079525">
    <tag k="cuisine" v="italian"/>
    <tag k="wheelchair" v="limited"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Pizzeria da Rocco"/>
    <tag k="amenity" v="restaurant"/>
  </node>
  <node id="392682646" version="3" timestamp="2010-05-11T19:00:20Z" uid="12973" user="MattGPS" changeset="4671372" lat="48.8315734" lon="9.5468864">
    <tag k="name" v="Gasthaus an der Wieslauf"/>
    <tag k="amenity" v="restaurant"/>
  </node>
  <node id="454516720" version="4" timestamp="2010-12-11T15:30:21Z" uid="12982" user="Michael Schulze" changeset="6625571" lat="48.8031264" lon="9.5344371">
    <tag k="addr:postcode" v="73614"/>
    <tag k="cuisine" v="regional"/>
    <tag k="website" v="http://www.deutscheshaus-schorndorf.de/"/>
    <tag k="addr:country" v="DE"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Deutsches Haus"/>
    <tag k="amenity" v="restaurant"/>
    <tag k="addr:street" v="Sonnenscheinstraße"/>
    <tag k="addr:city" v="Schorndorf"/>
    <tag k="addr:housenumber" v="13"/>
  </node>
  <node id="572362430" version="3" timestamp="2010-07-04T06:59:50Z" uid="106522" user="neuntoeter" changeset="5130101" lat="48.807953" lon="9.5379673">
    <tag k="smoking" v="no"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Club Kneipe"/>
    <tag k="amenity" v="restaurant"/>
  </node>
  <node id="613988559" version="1" timestamp="2010-01-15T01:20:03Z" uid="24748" user="mabapla" changeset="3621550" lat="48.7991827" lon="9.551828">
    <tag k="name" v="Gaststätte Schützenhaus"/>
    <tag k="amenity" v="restaurant"/>
  </node>
  <node id="859532091" version="1" timestamp="2010-08-13T23:05:14Z" uid="130472" user="fx99" changeset="5486736" lat="48.8062337" lon="9.5278548">
    <tag k="website" v="http://www.weinstube-buechsenmacher.de/"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Weinstube zum Büchsenmacher"/>
    <tag k="amenity" v="restaurant"/>
    <tag k="addr:housename" v="5"/>
    <tag k="addr:street" v="Höllgasse"/>
  </node>
  <node id="1625565012" version="1" timestamp="2012-02-09T18:00:04Z" uid="131968" user="changchun_1" changeset="10636279" lat="48.8151893" lon="9.5310692">
    <tag k="name" v="Gasthaus Sonne"/>
    <tag k="amenity" v="restaurant"/>
  </node>
</osm>
```

see the -fairly good !! - results i get when i run the xslt-processor on the second dataset: i have no glue why i get such nasty results - when i apply the xslt-processor on the first dataset...!?

```
185612117   48.8037523  9.5248779       Courage yes http://www.courage-restaurant.de/   DE  Schorndorf  Künkelinstraße  33

252619189   48.8067032  9.5314986       Kesselhaus  yes www.kesselhaus-schorndorf.de    DE  Schorndorf  Arnoldstraße    3

319597380   48.8277913  9.5477029       Gasthaus zur Linde                      

319597382   48.8282523  9.5503109       China-Garden                        

339591124   48.7888015  9.5079525   italian Pizzeria da Rocco   limited                 

392682646   48.8315734  9.5468864       Gasthaus an der Wieslauf                        

454516720   48.8031264  9.5344371   regional    Deutsches Haus      http://www.deutscheshaus-schorndorf.de/ DE  Schorndorf  Sonnenscheinstraße  13
```

any idea and pointer towards a solution is greatly wellcome... thx in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get good results: 11 rows in case 2 and one row in case 1:

```
25242198    49.0077605  8.3560676   german  Beim Schupi     http://www.schupi.de    DE  Karlsruhe   Durmersheimer StraÃŸe   6
```

Which is exactly what I would expect to get.
It would be strange for any xslt processor to fail a templated xslt sheet when only one record is present while working OK for multiple records.

I suggest you have another look, and if it still fails, let us know which xslt processor you are using.

Comment: hello dear maestro i am happy  to read your answer. i have uploadet the file - it is a bigger one  .- a geoinfoirmatics.file ..... i would be more than happy if you have  a closer look at it... any and all heli would be greatly appreciated https://rapidshare.com/files/2523227518/germany-001.xml   love to hear from you

Comment: OK 1 idea: try adding an `<osm>...</osm>` root around the `<node>` element in the first example, so that both files have the same structure.

Comment: hello maestro - many thanks: guess you have grabbed this 96mb file  which is quite a big file. Well i am very very happy  that you help me. i do so and add the things you adviced me and come back and report all my findings.. i come back tomorrow - on monday. many many thanks for your generours help

Comment: In the large file there are no nodes fulfulling the condition `node[tag[@k='amenity' and @v='restaurant']]`. Hence the output is empty.

Comment: hello dear Mestro13 - many thanks for the answer. hmm but there are also some restaurants in the  file... well i guess that we have to deo a rewrite of the xslt.processor to match the restaurants.... i am pretty sure that we have lots of findings (that are restaurants) within this file - what d o   you say - what  do you think about this thing,,,,  i look forward to hear from you

Comment: hello dear maestro - i would be happy if you can have a look at the options we have - to correct the xslt-processor.. in order to make it running on the large file  too... thx  alot

Comment: @zero scusi I had no time at all to look at this - what is the problem? Can you update the question to make that clear?

Comment: hello Dear Maestro13, thanks for answering; I have updated the question here in this new thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287116/xslt-processor-gives-back-only-a-little-subset-of-the-requested-matched-tags
Francis Avila gave me some hints and showed me some pointers to refine and re-engineer the xslt-processor. He gave great hints - but they go somewhat over my head - i am just a beginner. Can you give some hints how we should refactor the xslt-code that is shown in the other thread in the initial-posting. love to hear from you - in the **new thread** -thx in advance & greetings

Comment: sad thing that  you - maestro13 - wont help here...greetings - zero