# xslt-processor gives back only a little subset of the requested /matched tags

Tags: mysql, xml, parsing, xslt, openstreetmap

i have a extremely large xml-file - which is derived from the field of geo informatics. i got it from a German subsite or the OpenStreetMap-Project: the Geograpical-Engineering-site that deilvers a weekly snapshot of OpenStreetMap of a certain area: i took the germany.osm.bz2 from here http://ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/misc/openstreetmap/download.geofabrik.de/

For doing some tests with xslt i want to run a request to find out certain entity - let us take for example the restaurants. we want to find out all the restaurants in the area.

now we can run that directly on the  bz2 compressed file, that we downloaded - for example if we use the following code:

```
bzcat germany.osm.bz2 | xsltproc restaurants.xslt - > restaurants,csv
```

well i splitted the file with xml_split -which is a great perl-module from CPAN.

**The problem:** with the  following xslt-processor  i get only bad results - the parsed files werent not parsed enough i only get a minor set of informations when i run the code on a xml-file. see the xslt-processor - and below - a litte data-chunk out of the file i run and parse if you want to check it - just get the little dataset - note it is a splitted  file

here you can get it: https://rapidshare.com/#!download|643p12|2523227518|germany-001.xml|100000

Note: see therefore the important lines:   `xmlns:xml_split="http://xmltwig.com/xml_split"`
and this one here:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="xml_split:root/node/tag[@k='amenity' and @v='restaurant']">
```

**Note**- you can run a little test - and see how long it takes to parse
time xsltproc restaurants.xslt germany-001.xml > restaurants-001.csv

```
real    0m0.308s
user    0m0.283s
sys     0m0.022s
```

here we have the xslt-processor that contains the code for parsing - ( called atest3.xslt 
)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version = '1.0'
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:xml_split="http://xmltwig.com/xml_split"
        xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>

    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">

            <xsl:for-each select="xml_split:root/node/tag[@k='amenity' and @v='restaurant']">
            <xsl:value-of select="../@id"/>
            <xsl:text>&#x09;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="../@lat"/>
            <xsl:text>&#x09;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="../@lon"/>
            <xsl:text>&#x09;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="../tag[@k='name']">
                <xsl:value-of select="@v"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="./tag[@k = 'cuisine']/@v"/>
        <xsl:text>&#x09;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="./tag[@k = 'wheelchair']/@v"/>
        <xsl:text>&#x09;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="./tag[@k = 'website']/@v"/>
        <xsl:text>&#x09;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="./tag[@k = 'addr:country']/@v"/>
        <xsl:text>&#x09;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="./tag[@k = 'addr:city']/@v"/>
        <xsl:text>&#x09;</xsl:text>        
        <xsl:value-of select="./tag[@k = 'addr:street']/@v"/>
        <xsl:text>&#x09;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="./tag[@k = 'addr:housenumber']/@v"/>
        <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and here below we have a data-chunk out of the xml-file that we have parsed: see it

```
<node id="52768810" lat="48.2044749" lon="11.3249434" version="7" changeset="9490517" user="wheelmap_visitor" uid="290680" timestamp="2011-10-07T20:24:46Z">
    <tag k="addr:city" v="Olching" />
    <tag k="addr:country" v="DE" />
    <tag k="addr:housenumber" v="72" />
    <tag k="addr:postcode" v="82140" />
    <tag k="addr:street" v="Hauptstraße" />
    <tag k="amenity" v="restaurant" />
    <tag k="cuisine" v="mexican" />
    <tag k="email" v="info@cantina-olching.de" />
    <tag k="name" v="La Cantina" />
    <tag k="opening_hours" v="Mo-Su 17:00-01:00" />
    <tag k="phone" v="+49 (8142) 444393" />
    <tag k="website" v="http://www.cantina-olching.com/" />
    <tag k="wheelchair" v="no" />
</node>
```

see the results - note there are missing some parts - unfortunatly..

```
51923772    49.0812534  8.5637183   Zur Talschänke

52040576    49.4635433  12.4287292  Emil-Kemmer-Haus

52141326    49.4144243  12.4143153  Gasthaus Plecher

52623232    48.9293634  8.2722549   Korfu

52664989    49.0435133  8.3919370   Restaurant Zentrum

52754898    49.3243828  12.3618662  Gasthaus Irlbacher

52762875    49.0099641  8.2528132   Langasthof Stober

52765672    50.0082768  9.2139632   Wirtshaus im Frohnrad

52768810    48.2044749  11.3249434  La Cantina

52768816    48.2051698  11.3257964  Indian Palace

52768826    48.2073264  11.3276147  Dorfstub'n

52768830    48.2075968  11.3281055  Le Candele

52774284    49.0319471  8.2888353   Zum Anker
```

well it is somewhat a problem that i get the results - ive tried alot but at the moment i am glueless why i get the little output - that is totally contrary to the tags i have in the xslt -processor - any idea and hint will be greatly appreciatdd

btw: after all i want to run approx 5000 files that are the result of the split - and subsequently i want to collect all the results in a mysql-database...

here you can get the **original-file:** 
http://ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/misc/openstreetmap/download.geofabrik.de ( germany.osm.bz2  01-Apr-2012 14:51  1.7G )

and here a **splitted one:** 
https://rapidshare.com/#!download|643p12|2523227518|germany-001.xml|100000

i have to refactor the coed -so the question - is - how can i get the mysql-results on a efficient way?

**update:**thx to the first answer in this thread i startet to refactor the code - but still lack of some better results. i have to retry it again..lots of changes were suggested - i did a quick walktrough on the xslt-parser: with the first trial of refactoring i got some funny results. But i will try again - i go trough all the xslt-processor-code and have a closer look if i find the errors and  finally i try to refactor all the xslt-file. - any pointers and subbestions or code-snippets are greatly wellcome. Greetings your zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `./tag[@k = '???']/@v` xpath should be `../tag[@k='???']`, because your context node is your original matching `tag` element, not the `node` element.

You should consider changing your context node to make this code clearer and avoid errors like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="xml_split:root/node[tag[@k='amenity' and @v='restaurant']]">
```

Then you can use XPaths like `select="tag/@id"` and `tag[@k='country']/@v`.

But you should consider refactoring this code to make better use of `template` instead of `for-each`.

Comment: hello dear Francis Avila - many thanks for  the hints - that is great to see such great help i try to follow all your advices. Greetings

Comment: lots of changes you suggest - i did a quick walktrough on the xslt-parser: with the first trial of refactoring i got some funny results. But i will try again - i go trough all the xslt-processor-code and have a closer look if i find the errors and  finally i try to refactor all the xslt-file. - any pointers and subbestions or code-snippets are greatly wellcome. Greetings your zero

Comment: hello Francis - hello @ all - can u. give me some **helping hand** in **refactoring** the code!? That would be a great help. Thx alot